# Turn ¨Assemble¨ option on, in IDA Pro Demo

Tags: ida, patching

Is there a way to highlight "assemble" option in EDIT menu at IDA pro to apply a patch. Guess that `idagui.cfg` must be changed at some point, and turn NO to YES somewhere.

I use the last demo version.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about last demo version, but as far as I remember there is a following line in `cfg\idagui.cfg` that may be related.

```
DISPLAY_PATCH_SUBMENU    = NO           // Display the Edit,Patch submenu
```

Comment: thats correct for ida pro free, wich i cant use, because it gimme EACCESS VIOLATION warning.