# How can I patch this file?

Tags: ida, patch-reversing, bin-diffing

In viewing the diff for two files, a method in the original file starts with:

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
```

and in the modified file, it starts with:

```
push 0
pop rax
retn
endp
```

In essence, the modified file is patched to avoid running the method. My question is, what byte do I need to patch in IDA to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 3):

Something is wrong here, since the original `push ebp; mov ebp, esp` is 32 bit code, and the modified `pop rax` is 64 bit code. You might want to sort that out before proceeding.

That said, in IDA:

- locate the method in the graph view, or disassembly view. The bottom line in this view will show you the load address of the current instruction as well as the offset in the loaded file, this will help you finding the correct address
- put the cursor on the `push ebp` instruction`
- from the menu, use 'Edit/Patch program/Assemble'
- enter your assembly code, line by line
- when done, use 'Edit/Patch program/Apply patches to input file' to save back your changes

Comment: Also, see http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8980/1562 regarding editing `idagui.cfg`.

Comment: Yes, I mixed up both files... It accepts "push 0", but when I try to enter "pop rax", I get Invalid Operand warning in IDA